# How to I change font from bold to transparent in CSS file?

Tags: html, css, less, font-awesome

```
 .icon('FontAwesome', 13px, '\F058');
        color: green;
```

I am using the following code in the less file and getting an icon like this:
[image]

Actually what I want is this:

[image]

So what can I change in my less/css file ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you're using Font Awesome 4. In your CSS you're using the icon [fa-check-circle](https://fontawesome.com/v4.7.0/icon/check-circle), but you need [fa-check-circle-o](https://fontawesome.com/v4.7.0/icon/check-circle-o), so use this instead:

```
 .icon('FontAwesome', 13px, '\f05d');
```